# how do i distribute static library built using cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a cmake project which is a static library that i have to share with other teams in my company but just the .lib file and not the source code.
This library depends on Boost.

Now i build the library and transfer the install folder onto another pc (exe_pc) and use it in a exe project (this exe also depends on boost).
Now at compile time i get a linking error saying that `E:/Development/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/boost_system-vc140-mt.lib` cannot be opened.

so i open and check the generated LibTargets.cmake and it contains absolute paths of boost library for pc on which the library was built.

```
# The installation prefix configured by this project.
set(_IMPORT_PREFIX "C:/Program Files/cpp_licensing")

# Create imported target Licensing::liblicensing
add_library(Licensing::liblicensing STATIC IMPORTED)

set_target_properties(Licensing::liblicensing PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_COMPILE_DEFINITIONS "_LICENSING_DEBUG=0"
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/include"
  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "\$<\$<NOT:\$<CONFIG:DEBUG>>:E:/Development/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/boost_system-vc140-mt.lib>;\$<\$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:E:/Development/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/boost_system-vc140-mt-gd.lib>;\$<\$<NOT:\$<CONFIG:DEBUG>>:E:/Development/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib/boost_filesystem-vc140-mt.lib>;\$<\$<CONFIG:DEBUG>:E:/Development/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/debug/lib/boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd.lib>;cryptopp-static;wbemuuid"
)
```

LibLicensingTargets-release.cmake

```
et_target_properties(Licensing::liblicensing PROPERTIES
  IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LANGUAGES_RELEASE "CXX"
  IMPORTED_LOCATION_RELEASE "C:/Program Files/cpp_licensing/lib/licensing.lib"
  )

list(APPEND _IMPORT_CHECK_TARGETS Licensing::liblicensing )
list(APPEND _IMPORT_CHECK_FILES_FOR_Licensing::liblicensing "C:/Program Files/cpp_licensing/lib/licensing.lib" )
```

The user is supposed to have boost installed, the only problem i have is that because absolute paths are used in targets file user has to manually change them on his pc in the targets file.

what changes do i make to cmake so that the libraries built folder can be shared. **How do i distribute a library built using cmake ??**

Here is the cmake for the library project

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(liblicensing)

message("~~ Project: " ${PROJECT_NAME})

set(LIB_NAME "${PROJECT_NAME}")
set(PROJECT_VERSION 1.0)

include_directories(
        ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)

if (WIN32)
    find_package(Boost REQUIRED system filesystem)
    find_package(cryptopp REQUIRED)
    find_package(unofficial-date REQUIRED)
    include_directories(
            ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}
    )

else()
    find_package(date REQUIRED)
endif ()

file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADER_FILES include/*.h include/*.hpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES src/*.cpp)

add_library(${LIB_NAME} STATIC ${SOURCES} ${HEADER_FILES} )

set_target_properties(
        ${LIB_NAME}
        PROPERTIES
        OUTPUT_NAME "licensing"
        POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON
        CXX_STANDARD 14
        CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES
        CXX_EXTENSIONS NO
        LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX
)

if (MSVC)
    set_target_properties(${LIB_NAME} PROPERTIES DEBUG_POSTFIX "_d")
endif()

add_library(Licensing::liblicensing ALIAS ${LIB_NAME})

set(INSTALLATION_DIR "${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR "${INSTALLATION_DIR}/lib")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR "${INSTALLATION_DIR}/bin")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR "include")
set(INSTALL_CONFIGDIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${LIB_NAME})

target_include_directories(${LIB_NAME}
        PUBLIC
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}>
        )

if (WIN32)
    target_link_libraries(
            ${LIB_NAME}
            ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
            cryptopp-static
            wbemuuid
    )

else()
    target_link_libraries(
            ${LIB_NAME}
            cryptopp
            boost_system
            boost_filesystem
    )
endif ()

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
    target_compile_definitions(${LIB_NAME} PUBLIC _LICENSING_DEBUG=1)
elseif(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Release)
    target_compile_definitions(${LIB_NAME} PUBLIC _LICENSING_DEBUG=0)
endif()

# Expose Projects's public includes to other subprojects through cache variable.
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_INCLUDE_DIRS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include CACHE INTERNAL "${PROJECT_NAME}: Include Directories" FORCE)


###############
# Installation
##

install(TARGETS ${LIB_NAME}
        EXPORT LibLicensingTargets
        LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
        RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
#        INCLUDES DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
)

install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/include/
        DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}/${LIB_NAME}
        FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h*")

install(EXPORT LibLicensingTargets
        FILE LibLicensingTargets.cmake
        NAMESPACE Licensing::
        DESTINATION ${INSTALL_CONFIGDIR}
        )


#####################
# ConfigVersion file
##
include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
write_basic_package_version_file(
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/LibLicensingConfigVersion.cmake
        VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
        COMPATIBILITY AnyNewerVersion
)

configure_package_config_file(
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/CMake/LibLicensingConfig.cmake.in
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/LibLicensingConfig.cmake
        INSTALL_DESTINATION ${INSTALL_CONFIGDIR}
)

## Install all the helper files
install(
        FILES
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/LibLicensingConfig.cmake
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/LibLicensingConfigVersion.cmake
        DESTINATION ${INSTALL_CONFIGDIR}
)
```

Comment: Generated cmake files aren't designed to be portable, just distribute your shared library, your users need to write their own cmake files

Comment: @AlanBirtles but opencv does it, you can built it and share its build folder and it can be used in another cmake project by just setting a variable to it's cmake files folder

Comment: but only thing with opencv is that i build it as a shared lib and thus it dosen't  require any static library to be present

Comment: To make the component usable not only from the install directory but also from the build directory you can use the `export()` command. It makes the build folder contain the exported targets definition and usable for dependent projects. E.g., `export(
  TARGETS ${YOUR_TARGET_NAME}
  FILE ${YOUR_PACKAGE_BASENAME}-export.cmake
)`

Comment: In you case the command must read `export( TARGETS ${YOUR_TARGET_NAME} FILE ${YOUR_PACKAGE_BASENAME}Targets.cmake )`. If you use the targets provided by Boost (Boost::boost, Boost::filesystem, ...) rather than the `Boost_LIBRARIES` variable, the config file becomes reusable in the installation folder.

Comment: You build a **static** library `liblicensing`. So this library cannot contain Boost library. So your library can work on the target machine only if Boost library will exist on that machine. How do you expect Boost library to appear on that target machine? Do you expect a user to install Boost? Or do you want to copy Boost library alongside with your project? The way you want to handle Boost library very affects on the proper solution.

Comment: @Tsyvarev the user is supposed to have boost installed, the only problem i have is that because absolute paths are used in targets file user has to manually change them on his pc in the targets file.

Comment: Yes, now I understand your intention and the problem. Please, incorporate information from your last *comment* to the **question post**, so the question will be clear even without reading the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Not an entire answer but too much for a comment:

If you inspect your file `LibLicensingTargets.cmake` closely, you see that `cryptopp-static` and `wbemuuid` are not resolved down to the library level.

Looking at how you reference Boost you use the oldstyle version (`${Boost_LIBRARIES}`) that resolves down to the library level.

Try instead to use the targets provided by FindBoost.cmake module as follows:

```
if (WIN32)
    target_link_libraries(
            ${LIB_NAME}
            Boost::system
            Boost::filesystem
            cryptopp-static
            wbemuuid
    )

else()
    target_link_libraries(
            ${LIB_NAME}
            cryptopp
            Boost::system
            Boost::filesystem
    )
endif()
```

Another thing that puzzles me is why you added the `ALIAS`:

```
add_library(Licensing::liblicensing ALIAS ${LIB_NAME})
```

This `ALIAS` is properly created in the `LibLicensingTargets.cmake` file, so you do not need to create it on your own.

Another thing is, that you are giving your INSTALL command absolute paths. To make the package entirely relocatable you need to use relative paths (relative to the `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX`, the installation directory).

The following commands should therefore be changed to:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR "lib")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR "bin")
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR "include")
set(INSTALL_CONFIGDIR ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/cmake/${LIB_NAME})
```

If you further add the line:

```
export(TARGETS liblicensing NAMESPACE LibLicensing:: FILE LibLicensingTargets.cmake)
```

to your CMakeLists.txt, outside projects are able to import target from your build tree folder as of liblicensing was installed therein. See the CMake [documentation of the export command.](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/command/export.html?highlight=export)